# Question incorrectly marked as a duplicate...

Tags: discussion, support

I just posted this question:

[How can I control my Mac remotely?](https://superuser.com/questions/292904/how-can-i-control-my-mac-remotely)

It specifically asks how I can remotely control my Mac.

It was subsequently closed and marked as an "exact duplicate" of this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application

But they are hardly the same question.

My question is specifically asking about remotely controlling from one Mac to another.

The "duplicate" question revolves entirely around PC and certainly doesn't answer the question I posted.

Answer (score 9):

4 of the top voted applications are cross-platform and not PC specific.

[UltraVNC](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application/1666#1666)

[TeamViwer](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application/1812#1812)

[GotoMyPC](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application/1606#1606)

[Logmein](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application/1628#1628)

That's 4 recommendations right there - unless you mention why these won't work for out, I don't see why your question isn't a duplicate.

See also

- [Is it possible to remotely login to a Mac a la X11?](https://superuser.com/questions/8286/is-it-possible-to-remotely-login-to-a-mac-a-la-x11)
- [Remote Control software for Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/124355/remote-control-software-for-mac)
- [How can I create a remote connection between Mac & Windows computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/51863/remote-connection-between-mac-windows)
- [Frequently asked questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop+osx?sort=faq&pagesize=15) about [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) + [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx)
- [Frequently asked questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop+mac?sort=faq&pagesize=15) about [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) + [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac)
- [Frequently asked questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop?sort=faq&pagesize=15) about [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop)

et al.

There are too many similar questions, the duplicate link your question is the one most linked to from other questions

Comment: Well, if this is commonly unknown in the Mac community, the question will be raised again and again, and always get closed, always leading to explanation on meta?

Comment: @Userunknown the site shows questions with similar titles when posting a question http://i.imgur.com/shZpr.png

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, to provoke moderator attention, you would either use meta (as you do), use the chat (which you might have tried, without meeting any)  <strike>or edit your question</strike>, or flag your question yourself, which will raise mod-attention automatically, afaik.

It is meant to work, as if you improve your question, it can be reopened. Now your concern isn't to improve the question, but just to verify, that the moderator mentioned the OSX-relationship.

I'm not a Mac-user, and don't know, whether using a Mac or a PC is a relevant distinction. I would try it: 1. write a comment below your own question, then edit the question pro forma.

I'm not sure whether both is possible with 111 reputation - I hope so. :)

Comment: Provoke.. would be a wrong word :) Meta is the best place, chat is also good, but not all people visit chat. Editing won't raise mod attention, you could however flag for attention.

Comment: I*m not a native english speaker, so I looked it up in an online dict, http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=provoke and found about 20 synonyms in german, and all fit well. Maybe you think to much about a battle? But thanks for the flag-hint.

Comment: I think "challenge" would be the best word that you're looking for. fwiw I'm not a native English speaker either. Also, any one can edit - including you. You can comment on your own questions, for commenting on other questions, you need 50 rep. More about rep requirements are explained on the [Privileges page](http://superuser.com/privileges)

Comment: Yes, about the comments. No, I don't think 'challenge' is better.